# Why Does PartialView accept dynamic type argument

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am learning MVC and I like to learn why PartialViews are defined like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>
```

It is accepting dynamic as type argument. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not only Partial views that can have dynamic as their model, Views do this too. Why? Because dynamic signifies a type. But what type exactly will be known at run-time only. Using it as a view model allows for having a non-strongly-typed views. Another way of making your views non-strongly-typed is passing data to it by means of ViewBag object.